# disable jquery mobile form button action

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AJAX Form Submission in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012751/ajax-form-submission-in-jquery-mobile)

I have a form and I use jQuery to check and validate the form, so that, if the form is empty, it won't submit the form and will just alert "Please fill in all the fields".

```
function doShowError( eForm, sField, iInd, sError ) {
    var $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + "']", eForm ); // single (system) field
    if( !$Field.length ) // couple field
        $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + ']' + "']", eForm );
    if( !$Field.length ) // couple multi-select
        $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + '][]' + "']", eForm );
    if( !$Field.length ) // couple range (two fields)
        $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + '][0]' + "'],[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + '][1]' + "']", eForm );

    //alert( sField + ' ' + $Field.length );

    $Field.parents('div:first').addClass( 'error' );

    $Field
    .parents('div:first')
        .addClass( 'error' )
        .children( 'img.warn' )
            .attr('float_info', sError)
            //.show()
            ;
}
```

Right now, the problem is that, whenever I click on the submit button, I get redirected to the page (which is supposed to be the user-panel ) with just a text saying:

> undefined

How can I disable what the jQuery button do by default?

**Edit:** 
My event fires and the message shows , but I'm still redirected to the URL defined in the form's attribute `action`.

Comment: Hi! Where do you call your function `doShowError`? Could you provide more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function validating your form's fields (which should be called on `submit` event), you need to return `true` in the case where the validation is successful, and `false` otherwise.

In this way, you can prevent the form from navigating to the URL defined in the `action` attribute when the validation fails.

You may try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#your_form").submit(function() {
        // Define `sField`
        var sField = // SOMETHING

        // Define `iInd`
        var iInd = // SOMETHING

        // Define `sError`
        var sError = // SOMETHING

        return doShowError($(this), sField, iInd, sError);
    });
});
```

where `#your_form` is the ID of your form and `doShowError()` is the function verifying your form's input, returning `true` if all the fields are ok, and `else` in the opposite case.

In this case, you may need to modify your function `doShowError` so that it would return `true` or `false` as described above. You could change it to something like this:

```
function doShowError( eForm, sField, iInd, sError ) {

    // `haserror`: boolean output which will equal `true` 
    // if all the fields are correct, and `else` otherwise
    var haserror = true;

    var $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + "']", eForm ); // single (system) field
    if( !$Field.length ) { // couple field
        $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + ']' + "']", eForm );
        haserror = false;
    }
    if( !$Field.length ) { // couple multi-select
        $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + '][]' + "']", eForm );
        haserror = false;
    }
    if( !$Field.length ) { // couple range (two fields)
        $Field = $( "[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + '][0]' + "'],[name='" + sField + '[' + iInd + '][1]' + "']", eForm );
        haserror = false;
    }

    //alert( sField + ' ' + $Field.length );

    $Field.parents('div:first').addClass( 'error' );

    $Field.parents('div:first')
        .addClass( 'error' )
        .children( 'img.warn' )
            .attr('float_info', sError)
            //.show()
            ;

    return haserror;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response , but still facing the same problem ..
what my code should do is stay on the same page and just alert the error , but now i get to the action page , not only it but it has only `undefined`